# Data frame dynamic filtering

Tags: r

I would like to filter a data frame by a set of user defined columns and values.

Example data: `test`

```
  col1 col2 col3
1  1    a    4
2  2    b    5
3  3    c    6
4  3    c    7
```

If the user specified to use `c("col1", "col2")` to filter value `c(3, "c")`, I would expect the returned results to be the last two rows.

I've tried the following:

```
test[test[c("col1", "col2")]==c(3,"c"),]
```

However it gives the following results:

```
  col1 col2 col3
3  3    c    6
NA NA   NA   NA
```

Any idea why the last row is all NA?
And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to get the rowindex correctly.  It could be either a `vector` of `logical` or `numeric` index.  In the comparison (it is better to use `list` instead of `c` as we don't want to mix classes) we get a logical `matrix`  that needs to be reduced to a vector.  One option is `rowSums` and check whether the sum of each row is equal to 2 i.e. the number of columns used for comparison and subset the rows

```
test[rowSums(test[c("col1", "col2")] == list(3, 'c'))==2,]
#  col1 col2 col3
#3    3    c    6
#4    3    c    7
```

---

Now, we look at the difference in approach using `c` and `list`

```
test[c("col1", "col2")]==c(3,"c")
#  col1  col2
#1 FALSE FALSE
#2 FALSE FALSE
#3  TRUE FALSE
#4 FALSE  TRUE
```

Here, it is comparing elements by recycling the elements one after the another i.e. for 'col1', 1 is compared with 3, then 2 with 'c', followed by recycling of the vector i.e. 3 with 3 and again the next 3 with 'c'.  It follows the same way with the next column.

```
test[c("col1", "col2")]== list(3,"c")
#   col1  col2
#1 FALSE FALSE
#2 FALSE FALSE
#3  TRUE  TRUE  #note the change
#4  TRUE  TRUE
```

While, here, it compares the first column elements with the first element of `list` i.e. the `list` element is replicated or recycled followed by comparing the second column with second `list` element

Note that there are 8 elements i.e. 4 per each column.  So, it happens that there are 2 TRUE elements in the first case and 4 TRUE in the second case and there are 8 elements, however we have only 4 rows, so when the second column of logical matrix is not having rows, thus it creates the NA row for the TRUE value

```
test[test[c("col1", "col2")]==c(3,"c"),]
#   col1 col2 col3
#3     3    c    6
#NA   NA <NA>   NA
```

Similarly, there are 2 TRUE in each column, creating again double the number of NA rows

```
test[test[c("col1", "col2")]==list(3,"c"),]   
#   col1 col2 col3
#3       3    c    6
#4       3    c    7 
#NA     NA <NA>   NA
#NA.1   NA <NA>   NA
```

Suppose, we compare also the 3rd column, then there will be an extra NA row

```
test[test==list(3,"c", 5),]
#     col1 col2 col3
#3       3    c    6
#4       3    c    7
#NA     NA <NA>   NA
#NA.1   NA <NA>   NA
#NA.2   NA <NA>   NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here my `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(con = if_else(col1 %in% 3 & col2 %in% "c",TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  filter(con == TRUE) %>% 
  select(-con)  %>% 
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `dplyr`version with tidyeval

```
library(dplyr)
column_equals <- function(df, ...) {
  conditions <- quos(...)
  df %>%  
    filter(!!!conditions)
}

test %>%  
  column_equals(col1 == 3 & col2 == "c")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to extend [akrun answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47777667/588867) to a more real world example where data in the searched columns may contain `NA`. In those case, one will get "NA" rows in the final output which is messy and may confuse downstream analysis. In this example, I spiked columns `num` and `col2` with `NA` values. Only the `NA` in `col2` has effect because it is used in search. The root of this problem is anything that operates with `NA` gives `NA` (e.g. `NA == 1 = NA`), except `is.na`

```
mydf <- data.frame(num = c(1:3, NA, 5, 6), col1 = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), col2 = c('A', 'b', 'A', 'B', NA, 'D'), col3 = as.character(letters)[1:6])
getrows = mydf[c("col2", "col1")] == list("A", "a") # Mixing up column orders for fun
getrows = rowSums(getrows) == 2
getrows
mydf[getrows, ] # This gives undesired NA rows
# Use which to get exact row number
which(getrows)
mydf[which(getrows),]
```

Compare the output below:

```
> mydf <- data.frame(num = c(1:3, NA, 5, 6), col1 = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), col2 = c('A', 'b', 'A', 'B', NA, 'D'), col3 = as.character(letters)[1:6])
> getrows = mydf[c("col2", "col1")] == list("A", "a") # Mixing up column orders for fun
> getrows = rowSums(getrows) == 2
> getrows
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE    NA FALSE
> mydf[getrows, ] # This gives undesired NA rows
   num col1 col2 col3
1    1    a    A    a
3    3    a    A    c
NA  NA <NA> <NA> <NA>
> # Use which to get exact row number
> which(getrows)
[1] 1 3
> mydf[which(getrows),]
  num col1 col2 col3
1   1    a    A    a
3   3    a    A    c
```